# Mesibo Javascript messenger Integration for one to one and group video call

Tags: javascript, webrtc, videocall, mesibo

I have integrated Javascript Messenger & Popup https://github.com/mesibo/messenger-javascript/

I want use messenger for more than one user like Javascript Messenger where we can video call with multiple user (one-to-one or group call)

For that I have created multiple users from mesibo dashboard, the text chat is working properly but when I try to do a video call, I receive call on my other computer but the problem is that I can only see local stream and remote stream is not displayed and also no audio from call.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks

[console.log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uumN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using a secure URL (HTTPS) with a valid certificate. Calls will not work if you are using mesibo under a non-secure (HTTP) URL.

Start here before moving to messenger code https://github.com/mesibo/samples/tree/master/js/basic-demo

Comment: I tried with a self-signed certificate for https server, still getting same issue...

Comment: self-signed won't work. You need a valid certificate. 

Mesibo documentation mentions it https://mesibo.com/documentation/faq/demo-apps/#how-to-fix-getusermedia-error-when-making-calls-using-mesibo-javascript-api

Comment: @mesibo I did try on HTTPS, I actually couldn't find how to answer call javascript, 
API.answer(false) for a voice call. but this gives an error 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpung.png

is this the right function where I should answer, I sikked the UI part